# One year young - young

Tags: grammaticality

If somebody says my baby is one year young rather than one year old,is it grammatically acceptable?

Comment: It is done.  Most often for older people -- "He is 80 years young" -- but can be applied to anyone.  The intent (when used for older people) is to imply a youthful outlook/behavior -- not sure what the intent is for a baby, but certainly nothing sinister.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but I'd say applying to to a baby it makes the parent using it sound a bit inane or immature.

Comment: hashtag Benjamin Button

Comment: It's arguably acceptable, but if acceptable, it's best classed as an extragrammatical idiom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wow. We agree again - second time in a month!

Comment: @WS2 You must be slipping.

Comment: @WS2 - Which of you is the stopped clock?

Answer (score 1):

I would understand it; some people use it to try to be cute or something. I wouldn't use it formally, though.

Comment: If I was speaking "formally", I wouldn't use "cute" either.

Answer (score 1):

The way we speak of our age is based on the established **fact** and physical reality that all beings, from conception to birth, grow older with time. No exceptions.

We say: "The foetus is 10 weeks old."

But statements such as "I'm 60 years young" may be acceptable in informal conversations, but might become acceptable over time with respect to older individuals, who hate to think or say they're getting old.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what it is they are trying to emphasize. Both terms are relative so it might be used euphemistically.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct as a parallel to "one year old" but it is - in my own view - a nauseating and simpering attempt at a cute parody of the truth.